# FSMO errors on new Domain controllers

Tags: active-directory, netlogon, fsmo

I have a current DC that is on server 2012. I recently added 2 more dcs that are running server 2016. We are having issues with the netlogon share replicating across to the new dcs. When I look at the roles im getting some different results. netdom /query fsmo is showing me that everything is okay. Get-ADDomain | Select-Object DistinguishedName, SchemaMaster, DomainNamingMaster, InfrastructureMaster, PDCEmulator, RIDMaster is showing me that SchemaMaster and DomainNamingMaster dont have a dc that has that role. When I look at the gui to change the roles they are showing the same thing as netdom. Obviously it looks like netdom and get-addomain are somehow getting their information from different sources. Where can I go to see what those sources are?

Answer (score 0):

SchemaMaster and DomainNamingMaster are forest-wide FSMO roles.  You would need to run the following command to retrieve them

```
Get-ADForest | Select-Object *Master
```

Do you actually have any errors relating to the FSMO roles?  Or were you just performing due diligence in making sure everything was working okay?

Comment: That does show me what netdom displays. However im having issues with the netlogon share and replication across the domain.

Comment: This is becoming an XY problem. Do you want to figure out why netdom and Get-ADDomain show different results or do you want to resolve the replication problem?